# How to filter only art_track_video type using YouTube Content ID API?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to return only the assets that are art_track_video from the YouTube Content ID API. But since music_video and sound_recording are kinda connected with art track, the API returns me the three types of assets. Is there any way to filter even more, to display only the art_track_video type? Here's my code:

```
  def search_asset():
  asset_search_response_example = youtube_partner.assetSearch().list(
    onBehalfOfContentOwner=my_content_owner_id,
    type='art_track_video',
    sort='VIEWS'
  ).execute()
```

EDIT:

Current output:

```
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtubePartner#assetSnippet",
      "id": "A077448624358734",
      "type": "sound_recording",
      "title": "Test Asset",
      "isrc": "BRMKP0000000",
      "timeCreated": "2012-04-28T21:14:49.000Z"
    }
```

Desired output:

```
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtubePartner#assetSnippet",
      "id": "A077448624358734",
      "type": "art_track_video",
      "title": "Test Asset",
      "isrc": "BRMKP0000000",
      "timeCreated": "2012-04-28T21:14:49.000Z"
    }
```

If you the see the "type", you'll see that is returning me sound_recording, but I only want the art_track_video type.
I don't know if this helps to understand me better, if not, please ask me to edit again

Comment: Can you [edit] and add in your question the current and desired output?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I`ve updated the question