# Get ISRC from a YouTube video using YouTube Data API v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know that YouTube Music exists, and songs in YouTube Music are just YouTube videos, so I used the videos.list() function in the YouTube API, and I can't find the ISRC, an identifier for a specfic recording, anywhere in the results. I have searched the API documentation, and can't find anything regarding this.

Since the ISRC is retrievable using Spotfiy and Apple Music's API, I would assume YouTube Music would be using it too.

Does anyone know a way to find this information or if it even possible?

I am expecting to be able to get the ISRC from a YouTube Video if it has one.

After some research, I've discovered that this feature is available on the YouTube Content ID API, which is only available to YouTube Partners. I also saw this [question that includes a response from the YouTube Content API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69930580/how-to-filter-only-art-track-video-type-using-youtube-content-id-api)

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72822995).